# Небольшое меню с помощью HTML и PHP

Tags: html, bootstrap

Всем привет) Решил я сделать боковое меню на сайте, написал данный код, но столкнулся с проблемой, ссылки не кликабельны мышкой. Они кликабельны только колесиком и после этого открываются в новой вкладке. В чем причина и почему они не кликабельны левой клавишей мыши?

```
<!--    Левое боковое меню      -->
<div class="pull-left" id="sidebar">
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse list-group panel" style="overflow-y: hidden;" id="left-menu">
      <?php
         echo '<a href="/testsystem/" class="list-group-item nav-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#left-menu">Главная страница</a>';
         echo '<a href="/squiztopic/" class="list-group-item nav-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#left-menu">Темы</a>';
         echo '<a href="/squizquestion/" class="list-group-item nav-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#left-menu">Вопросы</a>';
         echo '<a href="/squizqa/" class="list-group-item nav-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#left-menu">Ответы</a>';
      ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Может можно сделать данное меню как то по другому? Подскажите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен)

Comment: Напишите в каком браузере проверяете, проверьте еще и в другом браузере.

Comment: @Oboroten проверил на хроме, фоксе и опере. везде только колесико работает. зашел на сайт с другой машины - тоже самое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, это из-за того, что вы используете функционал [Bootstrap Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

Он позволяет по клику на один элемент, раскрывать другой, связанный с ним, как спойлер. Этот функционал блокирует стандартное поведение по нажатию на ссылки.

Если это не то, что вам нужно, то удалите атрибут `data-toggle="collapse"` у ссылок.

```
<!--    Левое боковое меню      -->
<div class="pull-left" id="sidebar">
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse list-group panel" style="overflow-y: hidden;" id="left-menu">
      <?php
         echo '<a href="/testsystem/" class="list-group-item nav-header" data-parent="#left-menu">Главная страница</a>';
         echo '<a href="/squiztopic/" class="list-group-item nav-header" data-parent="#left-menu">Темы</a>';
         echo '<a href="/squizquestion/" class="list-group-item nav-header" data-parent="#left-menu">Вопросы</a>';
         echo '<a href="/squizqa/" class="list-group-item nav-header" data-parent="#left-menu">Ответы</a>';
      ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Буду знать)